# How to target a folder within a folder with regular expressions

Tags: python

For my project I've got a dataset with images that consists of folders within folders. These folders are labeled with "0" or "1". I need to target the directories that are labeled 0, in which I succeeded. Now I need to enter this directory and target all the files within this "0" directory, and here is why I failed. My code looks like this:

```
rootdir = "Data\\breast-histopathology-images\\Test"
regexfolder = re.compile('[0]')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    dirs = str(dirs)
    files = str(files)
    for directory in dirs:
        if regexfolder.match(directory):
            print(directory)
            for file in directory:
                print(file)
```

my code prints 4 times 0, while there are only 2 folders in the "Test" directory. How do I target and for example print out the Images in this 0 folder?

My folders look like this:

[Folderstructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jW9H.png)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: as a side-note, you usually don't want to use regex if not necessary. Here you can do: `if '0' in directory` instead of `if refexfolder.match(directory)` , which is easier to read

Comment: What do you get if you run `print(dirs)` and `print(files)` ?

Comment: Print(files) gives:

0
[]
0
[]

print(dirs) gives:

0
['0', '1']
0
['0', '1']

still not what we're looking for though. Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: I'm still not sure how the tree of folders looks. Could you add a couple pictures to your post?

Comment: `for file in directory:` You want `for file in files:` instead.

Comment: Hi guys, I posted a picture where you can see how my folder structure looks like. The 0 and 1 folder contain images. If I replace for file in directory with for file in files, I get:

0
[
]
0
[
]

Comment: In your code `dirs = str(dirs)` and `files = str(files)`, you converted two lists into str. Then `for directory in dirs:` just loop over the str.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
for file in directory:
    print(file)
```

You are looping through the characters of the directory (i.e one character - '0'), not the contained files. Os.walk should visit all your sub directories so just do this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    if os.path.basename(root) == '0':
        print('\n'.join(files))
```